# problem associated with web3.py installation on windows10

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, solidity, web3py

I tried installing web3, but I got the error in the picture below. I installed VS build tools using the link VS Code provided but I'm still getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: it will be help you https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i downloaded Vs build tools installer and installed the missing files

Answer (score 0):

The error report told you that you need to install Visual C++ 14.0 or greater.

[image]